# Tailwind CSS, class precedence is not respected

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following element:

```html
<td class="min-w-[10rem] max-w-[10rem] overflow-ellipsis text-sm text-text-light px-3 min-w-0"></td>
```

All of its class names are generated automatically through the component, except for the last one, `min-w-0`.

Since `min-w-0` is the last class name listed, I expect it to override `min-w-[10rem]`, the 1st class name listed.

However, for some reason, `min-w-[10rem]` seems to take precedence.

From Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Any insights as to why, and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tailwind sets the precedence by the order in which it adds classes to the CSS that's generated after scanning for utility-classes in your code. The order of the items in your `class` string will not make a difference.

You can, however, make `min-w-0` take precedence by adding a bang to the front of your class, e.g. `!min-w-0`. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier

A heavy-handed approach would be to use a library like tailwind-merge to strip the competing utility classes: https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge