# Tailwind text utility class not being overridden when adding a new text class to the list

Tags: tailwind-css

Here's my code...

**HTML:**

```html
<Button primary outline rounded>some text</Button>
```

**JS:**

```js
    const classes = className('flex items-center px-3 py-1.5 border', {
        'border-blue-500 bg-blue-500 text-white': primary,
        'border-gray-900 bg-gray-900 text-white': secondary,
        'border-green-500 bg-green-500 text-white': success,
        'border-yellow-400 bg-yellow-400 text-white': warning,
        'border-red-500 bg-red-500 text-white': danger,
        'rounded-full': rounded,
        'bg-white': outline,
        'text-blue-500': outline && primary,
        'text-gray-900': outline && secondary,
        'text-green-500': outline && success,
        'text-yellow-400': outline && warning,
        'text-red-500': outline && danger,
    })
```

**INSPECTED IN BROWSER:**

```html
class="flex items-center px-3 py-1.5 border border-blue-500 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-full bg-white text-blue-500"
```

I expected the button text color to be `blue-500` (overriding the `text-white` class), but it remains white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS, class precedence is not respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664539/tailwind-css-class-precedence-is-not-respected)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how CSS Cascade works - you can't expect it to be based solely on class order. The solution is to use a utility like [Tailwind Merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge), which strips out conflicting styles based on the order they appear in the string (which is what you are looking for).

You can combine it with your `classNames` function using something like this:

```js
export const cn = (...values) => twMerge(classNames(...values));
```